# Is there any example of definition-construction difference in engineering mathematics tools?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, definition

@Martin Brandenburg, in [his answer to one of my questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618021/why-are-equivalence-relations-essential-for-definitions-of-colimits-but-not-for), stated that the construction of a mathematical notion is not the same as its definition.

> The construction is not identical to the definition of something. The
> definition can be really abstract, whereas the construction must be
> concrete, often as concrete as possible in order to work with it.

He then stated an example of that difference:

> For example, you can define the completion of a metric space via its
> universal property, but its construction is done via equivalence
> classes of Cauchy sequences. Also here, there is no equivalence
> relation in the definition of the completion of a metric space.

In another related Q&A, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2782078/what-is-a-construction-in-mathematics), @Asaf Karagila also explains the difference, but I still cannot wrap my head around it (Maybe because I am not a mathematician.). So, is there any example of definition-construction difference regarding tools in applied mathematics (for example, those of real analysis)?

Comment: The natural numbers can qualify -- eg you can define a set of axioms that natural numbers satisfy (for example  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) and then construct natural numbers out of sets (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_ordinal)

Comment: "Definition" here should probably read "specification". So in the physical world, the specification might be a door more than 6 feet and 6 inches high: if you constructed a 6 feet 7 inch door you would have met that specification.

Comment: @RobArthan However, in these examples the object defined is unique in a very strong sense, while in your example, many different doors would still meet the specification.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: I think that is a moot point. You (and the OP) might like to look at Benecarraf's paper [What numbers could not be](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2183530.pdf) for the difference between constructions and specifications. I suspect the confusion here is between defining entities by construction (e.g., constructing the reals as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences) and defining properties (e.g., the property of being a complete linearly   ordered field). The latter specifies the real numbers, the former defines a system that meets that specification.

Comment: @RobArthan: Thanks for recommending that good read, most of whose points I find myself in agreement with. But I do not think it has a specific relevance for this question or the discussion in previous comments.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: the relevance of my comment was meant to be that Benecarraf shows how two very different constructions satisfy the same specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said "real analysis", here is one way to "define" differentiation (on polynomials $\in \mathbb R[x]$, say) rather abstractly, versus just "constructing" it:

*Definition*: $D$ is the operator $D: \mathbb R[x] \rightarrow \mathbb R[x]$ which satisfies i) $D(a\cdot p+q) = a\cdot D(p) +D(q)$ for all $a \in \mathbb R$ and polynomials $p$ and $q$, ii) $D(p\cdot q) = p\cdot D(q) + D(p) \cdot q$ for all polynomials $p,q$, and iii) $D(x) = 1$. (One can check this defines $D$ uniquely, i.e. if for two such operators $D_1, D_2$ satisfying these conditions one can show $D_1 = D_2$.)

*Construction*: $D(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \,x^k) := \sum_{k=1}^n k  a_k \,x^{k-1}$.